# Why event.preventDefault() function is so important?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, react-forms

I have faced a problem when I create a form in react for authentication. Without using `event.preventDefault()` nothing has happened when I click the submitted button. But when I use this it works fine. What is the reason behind this?

here is my code

```
const Login = () => {
  const signinWithGoogle=(e)=>{

      e.preventDefault(); // this is my Question

      console.log('click me');
      const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
      signInWithPopup(auth,provider)
      .then((result)=>{
          console.log(result);
      })
      .then((error)=>{
          console.log(error);
      })
  }
  return (
      <div>
      <Form >
      <Form.Group className="mb-3 w-50 m-auto " controlId="formBasicEmail">
        <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
        <Form.Text className="text-muted">
          We'll never share your email with anyone else.
        </Form.Text>
      </Form.Group>
    
      <Form.Group className="mb-3 w-50 m-auto " controlId="formBasicPassword">
        <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" />
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3 m-auto w-50" controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
        <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Check me out" />
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit" className=''>
        Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Group>
      <div>
      
      <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={signinWithGoogle}>Google Signin</button>
      </div>

    </Form>
     
      </div>
  )};
```

Answer (score 4):

The default behavior of a HTML `form` element is to submit the contents of that form to a server, process them there, and then load a new HTML page with the result.

Since you are instead processing the form in your client-side application code, you want to prevent this default behavior, and then show the result from your JavaScript code.